# Differentiable Convex Function with multiple global minimum.

Tags: functions, derivatives, convex-optimization

Does there exist Differentiable Convex Function with multiple global minimum (except for constant function)?

Comment: The answer is "yes" despite a theme in many answers that tend to "no, unless..." type answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an example convex, differentiable, and non-constant function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$
$$f(x) = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
(x-1)^4 &\mbox{ if $x \geq 1$} \\
0  & \mbox{ if $x \in [0, 1)$} \\
x^4 & \mbox{ if $x<0$} 
\end{array}\right. $$
This has an infinite number of global mins, and is consistent with the David Ullrich answer in that indeed we have $f'(x)=0$ over the entire interval $x\in[0,1]$.

Answer (score 1):

Unless the interval where the minima lie is constant, then no. Convexity implies that all local optima are global optima. If there were a interval where the values were not constant, where multiple local optima were global optima, it would violate the properties of convexity.

Try drawing it out for added intuition!

Comment: What do you mean by a "constant interval" or "non-constant interval"?

Comment: By "constant interval" I meant an interval where the values are constant. Apologies for the miscommunication, I've edited my post to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

No, not unless you count piecewise-functions which include a constant function like $y = 0$  for $-2<x<2$, $x^2-4$ else.

Answer (score 0):

No.  If $f$ is convex then $f'$ is non-decreasing, so we cannot have $f'=0$ at more than one point (unless $f'=0$ on an entire interval).

Comment: Actually the answer seems to be "yes" because we can have $f'(x)=0$ over an entire interval.

Comment: Of course the answer to the question, taken literally, is yes, because a function constant on an interval need not be literally constant.